# For loop is only outputting one nslookup result, when there are multiple

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, text-parsing, nslookup

I'm using `nslookup.exe` in a batch script, to print out all of the available IPv4 Adresses for an entered domain. But it is only printing out one of them, even if there are multiple.

I think I'm incorrectly parsing the results with my `for` loop, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

For example, if I enter `amazon.com` or `microsoft.com` as the domain name, then my output is like:

```
Domain Name: amazon.com
IPv4 Address: 205.251.242.103
```

```
Domain Name: microsoft.com
IPv4 Address: 20.112.250.133
```

But if I do a `nslookup` directly in cmd.exe, it prints out all of the addresses available, both IPv4 & IPv6:

```
C:\Users>nslookup amazon.com
Server:  xxxxxxxxx
Address:  xxx.xx.xxx.xx

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    amazon.com
Addresses:  54.239.28.85
          52.94.236.248
          205.251.242.103


C:\Users>nslookup microsoft.com
Server:  xxxxxxxxx
Address:  xxx.xx.xxx.xx

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    microsoft.com
Addresses:  2603:1030:c02:8::14
          2603:1020:201:10::10f
          2603:1010:3:3::5b
          2603:1030:b:3::152
          2603:1030:20e:3::23c
          20.231.239.246
          20.76.201.171
          20.70.246.20
          20.236.44.162
          20.112.250.133
```

I want all of the available IPv4 Addresses **only** for the entered domain.

```bash
for /f "tokens=2" %%b in ('nslookup -type=A !domain_name! 2^>nul ^| findstr /C:"Address"') do (
    if not "%%b"=="" (  
        echo Domain Name: !domain_name!
        echo IPv4 Address: %%b
    ) else (
        echo I encountered an error while looking up the domain name, or no Address records were found.
    )
)
```

I tried removing the `findstr`, and added `delims`, but it didn't work because it was printing an `UnKnown` as an IPv4 Address before printing the real IPv4 Address.

My `for` loop:

```bash
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%b in ('nslookup -type=A !domain_name! 2^>nul') do (
  if not "%%b"=="" (
    echo Domain Name: !domain_name!
    echo IPv4 Address: %%b
  )
)

if defined b (
  rem something was found
) else (
  echo No IPv4 addresses found
)
```

See the output:

```
Domain Name: microsoft.com
IPv4 Address:  UnKnown
Domain Name: microsoft.com
IPv4 Address:  20.231.239.246
```

I also used both `delims`, and `findstr`, creating another variable,`ipv4_addresses`, but for some reason, this also didn't work.

```bash
set "ipv4_addresses="
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%b in ('nslookup -type=A !domain_name! 2^>nul ^| findstr /R /C:"Address"') do (
  echo Domain Name: !domain_name!
  echo IPv4 Address: %%b
  set "ipv4_addresses=!ipv4_addresses! %%b"
)

rem If no IPv4 addresses are found, display a message
if not defined ipv4_addresses echo No IPv4 addresses were found for !domain_name!
```

Output was same, with just one IPv4:

```
Domain Name: microsoft.com
IPv4 Address: 20.236.44.162
```

This script is fine for a domain like `youtube.com`, or `google.com`, with only one  IPv4 Address, but not for a domain with multiple.

Comment: Please do not post text as images.  You spent more time creating those images and posting them on SO then it would have been to just copy and paste the text.

Comment: You want the IPV4 address so use `FINDSTR` limited regular expression capability to only find #.#.#.#.  example: `findstr /rc:"[1-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"`.  This only gets you about a quarter of the way to the finish line. You still need logic to `skip` the first couple of lines of output and a way to remove "Addresses".

Comment: You see, I did try this specific expression earlier `for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%b in ('nslookup -type=A !domain_name! 2^>nul ^| findstr /R /C:"Address: [0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"') `  but it's still not working. It prints only one IPv4 Address and I think it is able to skip IPv6.
I have been at this issue for a month now and I'm starting to think that it's impossible or something.
@Squashman

Comment: Well, I'm sure you meant to use `Addresses:` there, but obviously as only one line has that particular pattern, it doesn't match the ones below it!

Comment: @Compo @Squashman  
I didn't change that to `Addresses` in any of my tries. I tried it now and it's printing nothing. Just process the request and then  present the menu to try again.

Comment: Don't use addresses in your findstr. The addresses are on multiple lines.  By using addresses in your findstr you only get back one line. Basic logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually a single line. Filter for IPv4 address patterns and take care of the additional first token in the first line:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('NSLOOKUP amazon.com 2^>nul ^|more +3 ^|findstr /Rc:" [1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*"') do if not "%%b" == "" (echo %%b) else echo %%a
```

or more readable (and adapted to your additional requirement in the comments):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "domain_name=amazon.com"
echo Domain Name: %domain_name%
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (
  'NSLOOKUP %domain_name% 2^>nul ^|more +3 ^|findstr /Rc:" [1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*"
 ') do (
    if not "%%b" == "" (
      echo IPv4 Address: %%b
    ) else ( 
      echo IPv4 Address: %%a
    )
)
```

Output:

```
Domain Name: amazon.com
IPv4 Address: 54.239.28.85
IPv4 Address: 52.94.236.248
IPv4 Address: 205.251.242.103
```

Comment: It is partially working because now, it is able to fetch all the address but can seem to print the first IPv4 address. The output looks something like this now:
`Domain Name: amazon.com
IPv4 Address: Address:
Domain Name: amazon.com
IPv4 Address: Addresses:
Domain Name: amazon.com
IPv4 Address: 52.94.236.248
Domain Name: amazon.com
IPv4 Address: 54.239.28.85`
I changed the `for loop` to `for /f "tokens=1*" %%b in ('NSLOOKUP !domain_name! 2^>nul ^| findstr /R /C:"[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*"')`.
Am I still missing something here?

Comment: Can't tell without seeing your altered code. The output of my script is just three lines with only an IP4 Address in each. Are you sure you want to `echo` "Domain Name: " for each IP address? Note: for the first found address, it's token 2 (%%b) while it's token 1 (%%a)  for all others. You need to put the `echo`s into the if/else clauses, because they're different.

Comment: @Stephan I had to put in a `skip=1` otherwise it outputs my dns server ip address.

Comment: @Nelie if you are using Stephan's code as is, you should not get any of the output you say you are getting.  Try the literal code that was given to you.

Comment: @Squashman Yes, already guessed it would. (It's a IPv6 address on my system, so I didn't notice earlier.) Will add the `skip` with the next outstanding edit (depending on OPs answer to my comment)

Comment: @Stephan @Squashman I do want to `echo` the "Domain Name" once if there are multiple IPs.  I modified the code a bit more to overlook `Address` & `Addresses`. But it's not working for `amazon.com`, Amazon has 3 IPv4 but it's printing only two of them.
`for /f "tokens=1*" %%b in ('NSLOOKUP !domain_name! 2^>nul ^| findstr /R /C:"[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*"') do (
    if /i "%%b" neq "Address:" if /i "%%b" neq "Addresses:" (
        echo Domain Name: !domain_name!
        echo IPv4 Address: %%b
    )
)`
Could you please explain in a bit more depth?

Comment: Where's your `else` to show the first address? When you want to print something once, move it out of the loop.

Comment: @Squashman I used `more` to filter the data before iterating over it. Reason: `skip` would just skip the first IPv4 address and the dns server ip address could be IPv4 or IPv6

Comment: @Stephan The modified code you provided worked. I'm going to mark it correct. Thanks a lot, I genuinely appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You could of course forget about parsing the formatted text output type from `nslookup.exe` and instead use `powershell.exe` from your batch file:

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Resolve-DnsName -Name 'microsoft.com' -Type 'A' -ErrorAction 'Ignore' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'IPAddress'"
```

Where `-Type` `A` is IPv4.

If you are happy with less robust and difficult to read code then this can be shortened to:

```bash
@powershell -NoP "(Resolve-DnsName microsoft.com -Ty A).IPAddress" 2>NUL
```

Comment: It worked and looks amazing. Could you please provide some explanation? 
Because the thing is, I don't know a whole lotta about Powershell. I just want to see **Stephan**'s answer as well and see if it works well. Otherwise, I'm going to use your answer and mark it correct.
_Thanks a lot, Compo! I highly appreciate it._

Comment: TBH @Nelie, the best I can offer, other than simply telling you to start to learn how to use PowerShell, (which is sound advice), is to open a PowerShell Prompt, type `Get-Help Resolve-DnsName -Full` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to take a look at the output for the used command.

Comment: @Nelie there is nothing wrong with Stephan's code. It works as is. You seem to want to change the code and are screwing it up.

Comment: @Compo I will look into PowerShell and learn it as well, it looks powerful. 
Stepan's code worked. I'm marking that correct.
If anyone will be reading this then **This answer is also correct!**
Thanks, everyone!